# How autocomplete with javascript via api call

Tags: javascript, api, autocomplete

i'm trying to make auto complete with pure javascript.
Scenario is when type to input some letters it will search movies from omdbapi.

I make it like that:

i have input which users can search movies, i have get data from input value:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="searchMovie" value="">
```

and here i get movies and make html markup with javascript for show these results in html:

```
var searchInput = document.getElementById("searchMovie");

    // get movie
    searchInput.onkeydown = function() {
    var searchData = document.getElementById("searchMovie").value;

    if (searchData.length >= 3 ) {
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('GET', 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=' + searchData + '&apikey=000000', true);
        request.onload = function () {
            // Begin accessing JSON data here
            var data = JSON.parse(this.response);

            const wrapper = document.createElement('div');
            app.appendChild(wrapper);
            var results = data;
            if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
                console.log(data);
                Object.keys(data.Search).map(function(key, index) {
                    console.log(data.Search[index].Title);

                    const searchResultsContainer = document.createElement('div');
                    searchResultsContainer.setAttribute('class', 'row');

                    const h1 = document.createElement('h1');
                    h1.textContent = data.Search[index].Title;
                    wrapper.appendChild(searchResultsContainer);
                    searchResultsContainer.appendChild(h1);
                    console.log(searchResultsContainer);
                 });
            } else {
                console.log('error');
            }
        };
        request.send();
    }
  };
```

everything work well but problem is:

when i try to delete keyword which i wrote and write new one results not disappear from html, i want change

Comment: are you saying that new results won't show up or that they do but the old results won't go away?

Comment: yes old results won't go away

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to capture the change in the text input. Adding your code to a function and binding the input to oninput function. When there is a change in the value of the input it will rerun the api call. Furthermore, you need to clear out the old result.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="searchMovie" value="" oninput"apiCall()">

<script>
function apiCall(){
 var searchInput = document.getElementById("searchMovie");

    // get movie
    searchInput.onkeydown = function() {
    var searchData = document.getElementById("searchMovie").value;

    if (searchData.length >= 3 ) {
       while (document.getElementsByClassName('autoComplete')[0]) {
    document.getElementsByClassName('autoComplete')[0].remove();
}

        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('GET', 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=' + searchData + '&apikey=000000', true);
        request.onload = function () {
            // Begin accessing JSON data here
            var data = JSON.parse(this.response);

            var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
            wrapper.className = "autoComplete";
            app.appendChild(wrapper);
            var results = data;
            if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
                console.log(data);
                Object.keys(data.Search).map(function(key, index) {
                    console.log(data.Search[index].Title);

                    const searchResultsContainer = document.createElement('div');
                    searchResultsContainer.setAttribute('class', 'row');

                    const h1 = document.createElement('h1');
                    h1.textContent = data.Search[index].Title;
                    wrapper.appendChild(searchResultsContainer);
                    searchResultsContainer.appendChild(h1);
                    console.log(searchResultsContainer);
                 });
            } else {
                console.log('error');
            }
        };
        request.send();
    }
}
</script>
```

That should remove the wrapper element you added and its children and populate a new one with new data. I can't really test this to make sure it works as I can not see the rest of your code. But it should work. if not I can help you to figure out any errors.

Also, I would consider making wrapper just a hidden div that you can easily clear and unhide when needed. It would be much easier and you wouldn't need to add and remove so many elements. just `wrapper.innerHTML = "";` then `wrapper.innerHTML = newRowSet;` and done

Comment: Thanks it's worked well just some problem, if i wrote batm eg: batman movies listing if i wrote batman, batman movies not listing.

Comment: hmm... I would think that is either on the api side If you are sending the data and its not returning a result, Check developer tools to see the network and make sure you are sending the data.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting `h1.textContent = data.Search[index].Title;` update this to `h1.innerHTML = data.Search[key].Title;`